# How do I force Oracle Managed ODP.NET to always set the session's globalization to the threads?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, globalization, odp.net

I am struggling to find what the session's globalization defaults to in Oracle Managed ODP.Net.

From experience (and [an answer to another of my questions relating to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388534/how-do-i-set-my-oracle-sessions-globalization-to-be-the-same-as-windows-in-net)), it seems to default to the thread's cultures but only the first time the actual connection is made to the database, not when the connection is reused from the pool.

Does anyone know exactly how this globalization defaulting works for managed ODP.NET or how to always force it to set the session's globalization to the threads?

Comment: Don't have the answer to this immediately (may reply later), but I know that there is an upcoming feature (ODP.NET 12.2) called "connection pool tagging" that will allow you to set a tag for all sessions you have set to a certain setting. Then you can search the pool for the specific tags you want.

Comment: Thank you Christian Shay, that sounds interesting, For example, I would tag the pool only to return connections for the culture I want. Still would need to map the .NET's thread current culture to Oracle's globalization...

Comment: I need to correct my comment above. Unfortunately, the connection tagging feature will not be in the next release. It has been pushed off to a (unspecified)  later release. However, ODP.NET 12.2 (ODAC 12.2 rel 1) WILL introduce a callback mechanism you can use that will allow you to do any kind of connection setup required everytime a connection is removed from the pool. So you will be able to change the language to the default you want upon removing from pool. You can still do that now explicitly of course, it's just not as convenient as a callback.